# Force ICMPV6 packet using envelope icon

Tags: packet-tracer, icmpv6

I play with Packet Tracer 6.2 using IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, trying to ping routers using the envelope icon.

When both routers are IPv4 or IPv6, clicking envelope correctly chooses between ICMP and ICMPv6 packets. But I can't seem to use it when source server uses IPv6 and destination both IPv4 and IPv6. Envelope chooses IPv4 and fails.

I failed to use complex PDU - the source ip is 0.0.0.0.

When I try to ping from console, ping using IPv6 has 100% success rate. I can live with that, but is there some more comfortable way like Mr. Envelope?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to do an IPv6 ping with an IPv4 source address (`0.0.0.0` is an IPv4 address, not an IPv6 address)? The IPv6 equivalent for the IPv4 address `0.0.0.0` is `::`.

Comment: I'm trying to ping IPv6 destination with IPv6 source address. The problem is that the destination has also IPv4 address and clicking envelope chooses IPv4, which is not set on the source. I can manualy ping from console, but not from the IDE (the envelope icon).

Comment: Apparently, you aren't the only one with envelope ping problems: [packet tracer , can ping through CLI but not with the envelope button.](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/11450186/packet-tracer-can-ping-through-cli-not-envelope-button)